# How to reinstall Ruby and Gem on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, uninstallation

I am trying very hard to uninstall Ruby and Gem from my computer so that I can do a complete reinstall of all, since I've clogged up a few errors and crossed wires.

When I do `sudo uninstall gem` I get the following progress/message:

```
Preparing Uninstall...
Uninstall Began...
Uninstall Failed...
Reason: ErrorMissingBundle
```

I'm NOT, I repeat NOT at this point looking to install rvm, since I just want to clean out my computer and get rid of the bugs before I install anything else.

Comment: I think you might be able to just do a reinstall, and that should overwrite the issues. However, I think there is no uninstaller for ruby gems or ruby. It's a matter of deleting the relevant files. Have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115803/how-can-i-uninstall-ruby-on-rails-on-mac-os-x to get details on where your ruby install might be to delete it. Then just rf -rm.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Completely reinstalling Ruby Rails and Gem on Mac OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316026/completely-reinstalling-ruby-rails-and-gem-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: This is a duplicate question, you need to add the details to your original post. Starting a new one just clutters the site up. Did you get ruby and RubyGems through the Developer Tools package?

Comment: I did. I obviously had Ruby to begin with, then installed RubyGems and Rails from the terminal.

... Annoyingly in my attempt to clean the slate and get rid of anything I'd downloaded/wrongly amended, I removed XCode Tools and now get an error everytime I try to reinstall.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say how far you had gotten in the process, but all you have to do is remove the Ruby directory (grep for it) and the gems will go away with it. You'll probably have to update your paths as well.

But, you really should use RVM. If you install it correctly those errors you see will not affect you because you will be using the RVM installed Ruby and gems. Also, the system installed Ruby is sometimes used in apps and if you remove it you could break those apps.

More information in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591501/how-to-uninstall-ruby-from-usr-local).