# Unable to uninstall Ruby 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, rvm, bundler

i'm using rvm, i installed ruby 2.0 with rvm but i need to uninstall it to get ruby 1.9.3. But my terminal is doing strange things:

```
MacBook-Pro-Kuba:~ Kuba$ gem install bundler
Successfully installed bundler-1.3.5
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.3.5
1 gem installed
MacBook-Pro-Kuba:~ Kuba$ sudo rvm all do uninstall ruby
Preparing Uninstall...
Uninstall Began...
Uninstall Failed...
Reason: ErrorMissingBundle
```

So as you can see i'm definitely having bundler installed, and it's throwing this error. What should i do? 
(i use mountain lion)

Comment: Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319495/how-to-reinstall-ruby-and-gem-on-mac-os-x

Comment: i dont see my solution there... users there tell this guy to use rvm which im already using

Comment: explaining your command problems 1. `sudo` losses whole environment you should not prefix your commands with sudo, if you have to - use `rvmsudo`, 2. `rvm ... do ...` runs any commands it does not assume the command is prefixed with `rvm`, so your command meant to run system command `uninstall` in every ruby in rvm, not to uninstall every ruby, that would be: `rvm uninstall all`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you need to uninstall ruby2.0 to get ruby1.9.3? The whole idea of rvm is that you can have (and switch between) many different versions.

List the Rubies with `rvm list`.

Install (if required) with `rvm install 1.9.3`.

Swap to it with `rvm use 1.9.3`.

Comment: thats what i figured out eventually;)